# How can you see the device history of a computer when doing forensics?

Tags: forensics

I was reading [this post](http://yro.slashdot.org/comments.pl?sid=2657361&cid=38954233) on Slashdot which talks about the process of gathering evidence from a computer as part of an investigation. The post mentions being able to see the history of devices connected to a computer when doing forensics work, as well as which files were transferred to which devices:

> But as we dig deeper, we'll begin to look at devices that were
>   connected to the operating system. We'll match up the devices in our
>   possession with the ones recorded by the os. We'll look for behavioral
>   patterns of file movements from the OS to the device and then back.

Is it possible to see device history and which files were transferred to a given device when doing computer forensics? If so, which tools allow you to see this?

Comment: i use this program to see any usb device that connect to my computer.. and it worked... http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html

Answer (score 8):

I can answer the first part. At least on Windows 7, you can see USB device history to some extent by viewing the Registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USBSTOR

See the screenshot for an example of the content. This would allow you to confirm if a particular USB device had been connected to a particular computer.

I am not aware of any mechanism native to windows that would allow someone to view file transfer history to USB drives, and I'd be very interested to find out!

[image]

Comment: Thanks scuzzy. Given the name of the registry branch is USBSTOR, I am guess it doesn't apply to firewire or eSATA devices? Or are they in a different part of the registry?

Comment: I don't know of any equivalent history storage for firewire/eSATA devices, but I'm far from an authority on the subject :) Someone with more experience may be able to comment further.

Comment: OK, thanks. Also, does this actually identify a USB device specifically, or only make and model?

Comment: I believe the key name immediately below the make and model is a UID if the second character is not a "&". I would verify this experimentally though before relying on it for anything substantive.

Answer (score 2):

This tool ([USB DView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html)) allows you to pull a list of USB devices that have been attached to the computer at some stage by pulling the information mentioned in below answers and displaying it simply like so: [image: From Nirsoft.net]

> For each USB device, extended information is displayed: Device
>   name/description, device type, serial number (for mass storage
>   devices), the date/time that device was added, VendorID, ProductID,
>   and more...  USBDeview also allows you to uninstall USB devices that
>   you previously used, disconnect USB devices that are currently
>   connected to your computer, as well as to disable and enable USB
>   devices.

([Source as above](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html))

For the other part of your question as to determining file transfer history, this depends on a number of things but utimately, operating systems don't generally store this much information as show in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/425625/how-to-find-windows-7-file-transfer-history). You can make modifications to your system in order to log such information but its not 'enabled by default'. I presume the reason why is because it would use up a huge amount of disk space in a very short time (if you copy millions of small files to a USB stick the logs will be enormous depending on the detail you are logging).

Comment: Yeah. I've used this tool before. BT unsure of how the list of transfers can be found.